# Dynamic version of MKTHNUM

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am attempting to solve a dynamic version of MKTHNUM. The static version involves a given array of N elements where we have to answer queries q(l, r, k) in the subarray from l to r, determining the kth element when considering the subarray sorted. I have successfully addressed this initial part using a persistent segment tree. Now, I aim to perform updates in the array. Given an index and a new value, I want to update the array as follows: a[index] = val, while still being able to handle queries q(l, r, k).

https://www.spoj.com/problems/MKTHNUM/

I used a persistent segment tree, but I can't get the updates right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_VALUE = 1000000; 

struct Vertex {
    int sum;
    Vertex* left, *right;

    Vertex(int val) : sum(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    Vertex(Vertex* l, Vertex* r) : sum(0), left(l), right(r) {
        if (l) sum += l->sum;
        if (r) sum += r->sum;
    }
};

Vertex* build(int tl, int tr) {
    if (tl == tr) {
        return new Vertex(0);
    }

    int tm = (tl + tr) / 2;

    return new Vertex(build(tl, tm), build(tm + 1, tr));
}

Vertex* update(Vertex* v, int tl, int tr, int pos) {
    if (tl == tr) {
        return new Vertex(v->sum + 1);
    }
    int tm = (tl + tr) / 2;

    if (pos <= tm) {
        return new Vertex(update(v->left, tl, tm, pos), v->right);
    } else {
        return new Vertex(v->left, update(v->right, tm + 1, tr, pos));
    }
}

Vertex* insert(Vertex* old, int tl, int tr, int val) {
    if (tl == tr) {
        return new Vertex(old->sum + 1);
    }

    int tm = (tl + tr) / 2;

    if (val <= tm) {
        return new Vertex(insert(old->left, tl, tm, val), old->right);
    } else {
        return new Vertex(old->left, insert(old->right, tm + 1, tr, val));
    }
}


int find_kth(Vertex* nl, Vertex* nr, int tl, int tr, int k) {
    if (tl == tr) {
        return tl;
    }

    int tm = (tl + tr) / 2, left_count = nr->left->sum - nl->left->sum;

    if (left_count >= k) {
        return find_kth(nl->left, nr->left, tl, tm, k);
    }

    return find_kth(nl->right, nr->right, tm + 1, tr, k - left_count);
}



int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n, q;
    cin >> n;

    int tl = 0, tr = MAX_VALUE + 1;
    vector<Vertex*> roots;
    vector<int> a(n);

    roots.push_back(build(tl, tr));
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) cin >> a[j];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        roots.push_back(update(roots.back(), tl, tr, a[i]));
    }

    cin >> q;
    while (q--) {
        int type, idx, val;
        cin >> type;
        if (type == 1) {
            cin >> idx >> val;
            a[idx] = val;
            roots[idx + 1] = insert(roots[idx], tl, tr, val);
        }
        
        if (type == 0) {
            int x, y, k;
            cin >> x >> y >> k;
            
            int result = find_kth(roots[x], roots[y+1], tl, tr, k+1);
            cout << result << endl;
            
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, what is your *focused* C++ question?  Then also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: I've got no idea what the semantics of `update` and `insert` should be, but I'm fairly certain that the code doesn't do the right thing. And that's probably caused by a lack of clear English semantics - why isn't there a comment that is clearly describing what those functions should do? For instance `update(v,0,0,0)` does not update `v` at all.